# Motives under de-singularization

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a singular variety over a field $k$ of characteristic 0.

Suppose a minimal resolution of singularities of $X$, $f:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X$, exists, i.e., $\tilde{X}$ is a smooth projective variety, $f$ is a proper birational morphism and every resolution of singularities of $X$ factors through $f$.

What is the most one can say about the relationship between the motives and motivic cohomology of $X$ and $\tilde{X}$?

A simple illustrative example would be very helpful as would any references.

Comment: There is a "formula" (more precisely, a distinguished triangle) for the motive of a blow-up (hence, a long exact sequence for motivic cohomology), which you can find e.g. in Voevodsky et al., *Cycles, Transfers and Motivic Homology Theories*, (4.1.3).

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault, Thank you!